# Loop ajax request one by one and show result one by one?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to check whether some email addresses are registered on a website or not with cURL function.

So in this case I have 3 `textarea` elements. The first contains lists of email, the second contains live email (indicated that email is registered) and the third contains unregistered email. Then there is button called "Check", if user clicks this then it makes an AJAX request, one after another, and shows result one after another, instead of multiple AJAX request in one time (`async: true`) or one by one AJAX request but one time result at the end of request (`async: false`).

The problem if I use `async: true` my browser will crash for big lists and if I use `async: false` I don't know whether my application is running or not since it shows the result at the end of request, even request is one after one.

Then so to make my question simple here is my code.

```
$("div#check").click(function(){
    //Assume i just grab email lists from text area and put in array
    var mail_lists_clean = ["a@yahoo.com", "b@aol.com", "c@gmail.com"];
    var promises = [];

    $.each(mail_lists_clean, function(index, value){
        var promise = $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "valid_check.php",
            //cache: false,
            async: false,
            data: { 
                email: value 
            }
        }).success(function(data) {
            if (data == "live") {
                //append email to second textarea 
            } 
            else {
                //append email to third textarea
            }
        });
        promises.push(promise);
    });

    $.when.apply($, promises)done(function() {
        alert("All Request done!");
    }).fail(function() {
        console.log("error");
    });
});
```

Can anyone help me make AJAX requests one after another and show results one after another? Please correct my code above. Thanks.

Comment: If you are crashing when using huge lists, then dont use huge lists, paginate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make ajax call one by one

you need to make recursion call at `$.ajax` `success` callback function.

```
function ProcessEmailList(mail_list) {
  // process one email at a time
  var value = mail_list.pop();

  // if there is email in the array
  if (value) {
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "valid_check.php",
      async: false,
      data: {
        email: value
      }
    }).done(function(data) {
      if (data == "live") {
        //append email to second textarea 
      } else {
        //append email to third textarea
      }

      // recursion call, process rest of the email
      ProcessEmailList(mail_list);
    }).fail(function() {
      console.log("error");
    });
  } else {
    // no more email in the array, we have processed all
    alert("All Request done!");
  }

};

$("div#check").click(function() {
  //Assume i just grab email lists from text area and put in array
  var mail_lists_clean = ["a@yahoo.com", "b@aol.com", "c@gmail.com"];
  ProcessEmailList(mail_lists_clean);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not pass All the emailadresses at once in a single ajax request separated by a certain character and pass the result back? That way long lists of addresses wont be a problem and it Will save You a lot of hassle of figuring out which request was handled and which one wasnt. It would Be better for performance as well.